# Laravel Transactions with model and DD

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I am developing a laravel application which is multi DB application,
where
`Laravel Version is 9`,
`Database is pgsql`

I am facing an issue with transaction where I am using

```
try{

    DB::connection(DB_1)->beginTransaction();
    
    $product = Product::find($id);
    
    $product->status = 1;
    $product->update();
    
    $product->refresh();

    dd($product);
    /* 
        here if I do dd(), and exit from script,
        and check in DB, then I can see status of this to updated with '1'
        but I have not committed this transaction yet.
    */

    DB::connection(DB_1)->commit();

}catch(Exception $e){


    DB::connection(DB_1)->rollBack();


}
```

here, I want to understand, how laravel refresh() method works with transaction.
Also How can I manage transaction it with Eloquent Model too.

Comment: does [this](https://gist.github.com/vielhuber/351c241211aee180fe344f0457901653) help you?

Comment: In my setups, the transaction has to begin before the try, and commit after the catch, rollback is in the right place

Comment: I tried with starting transaction before try start, and at the end of try, I am committing it, but still it is not rollbacking my transaction on error or on `dd()` too.